# Picking the highest number in a list of strings

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a string list with "numbers":
`"Rain Probability": [ "100", "95", "95" ]`

And I want to be able to get only the highest one. I then put everything in a List called "result" but instead pf the string list I want just the highest number.

`

```
public List<WeeklyForecast> convert(){

        AllForecast allForecast = Templates.restTemplate(restTemplate);
        List<NextDays> something = allForecast.getNextDays();
        List<WeeklyForecast> result = new ArrayList<WeeklyForecast>();
        
        
        for (int i=0; i< something.size(); i++){
            NextDays before = something.get(i);
            WeeklyForecast weekly = new WeeklyForecast(
              before.getData().getData(),
              before.getTemperature().getMaximumTemperature(),
              before.getTemperature().getMinimumTemperature(),
              before.getRain());

            result.add(i,weekly);
        }
        
        return result;
       
       // before.getRain().stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).max().orElse(-1)     
     
        
    }
```

`

This is my WeeklyForecast Model:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class WeeklyForecast {

    @JsonProperty("Date")
    private String data;

    @JsonProperty("Maximum Temperature")
    private String tempMax;

    @JsonProperty("Minimum Temperature")
    private String tempMin;

    @JsonProperty("Rain Probability")
    private int rain;

}
```

And the NextDays object:

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class NextDays {

```
@JsonProperty("@attributes")
private NextDate data;

private List<String> rain;

@JsonProperty("temperatura")
private NextTemperature temperature;

public NextDays(){
    rain = new ArrayList<>();
}

public NextDate getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(NextDate data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public NextTemperature getTemperature() {
    return temperature;
}

public void setTemperature(NextTemperature temperature) {
    this.temperature = temperature;
}

@JsonSetter("prob_precipitacion")
public void setNextRain(JsonNode nextRain) {

    if (nextRain != null) {
        if (nextRain.isTextual()) {
            rain.add(nextRain.asText());
        } else if (nextRain.isArray()) {
            for(JsonNode node : nextRain) {
                rain.add(node.asText());
            }
        }
    }
}

public List<String> getRain() {
    return rain;
}
```

}

I have to convert the string list into an int rigth? How can I do it?
I want to do this inside de "for" cycle is possible.
Regards.

Comment: @Dattq2303 I did try that but I can't work it out inside the "for" cycle

Comment: You need to add NextDays object to your question. And also be clear about what you want. Please edit your question.

Comment: So you want to have only one element in WeeklyForecast.rain list? If you want to have just highest number there instead of list you need to change your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
public List<WeeklyForecast> convert(){

    AllForecast allForecast = Templates.restTemplate(restTemplate);
    List<NextDays> something = allForecast.getNextDays();
    List<WeeklyForecast> result = new ArrayList<WeeklyForecast>();
    
    
    for (int i=0; i< something.size(); i++){
        NextDays before = something.get(i);
        WeeklyForecast weekly = new WeeklyForecast(
          before.getData().getData(),
          before.getTemperature().getMaximumTemperature(),
          before.getTemperature().getMinimumTemperature(),
          before.getRain().stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).max().orElse(-1));

        result.add(i, weekly);
    }
    
    return result;   
}
```